# Grouping input and output signals with the corresponding clock

Tags: verilog, hdl, quartus, sdc

In my Verilog design, I have two asynchronous clocks, `clk1` and `clk2`. Associated with each clock is a bunch of inputs and outputs.

At the moment, my compiler (Quartus II) is not complaining when I mix I/O signals associated with `clk1` with I/O signals associated with `clk2`. This is bad because the signals need to be synchronised when crossing clock domains.

What is the best way to constrain I/O signals to an associated clock? I have seen the SDC commands `set_input_delay` and `set_output_delay`, but I have set all the delays to `0` and I fear this might be the wrong way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an 'error' to sample data from one clock domain in another. Quartus will not prevent you doing it at design entry/synthesis stage. When you later run timing analysis with `quartus_sta` you will find that the register path between the two clocks (if truly different) is unable to make timing.

You are running timing analysis, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm running timing analysis. I'm just wondering how to make the register path between the two clocks "make timing" in a graceful way. At the moment I'm using `set_false_path` but that may be a little too aggressive.

Comment: `set_false_path` is the accepted technique. This gives the fitter complete freedom in the routing of the path - if it decides a few trips around the peripheral of the chip is required, so be it.